# RuleBasedRenderer with two different symbols using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to create a RuleBasedRenderer with two layers. The first layer is used to fill the polygons and the other should create a hatching effect with lines. However, the code below, creates the layers needed, but both line color and fill color are the same. Do you know how can solve this?

```py
        symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
        symbol.deleteSymbolLayer(0)
        symbolLayer2 = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer()
        symbolLayer1 = QgsLinePatternFillSymbolLayer()
        symbol.appendSymbolLayer(symbolLayer1)
        symbol.appendSymbolLayer(symbolLayer2)
        renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)
        # get the "root" rule
        root_rule = renderer.rootRule()

        for label, expression, color_name in rules:
            # create a clone (i.e. a copy) of the default rule
            rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
            # set the label, expression and color
            rule.setLabel(label)
            rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
            if color_name == 'orange':
                print(len(rule.symbols()))
                rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color_name))

            else: rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color_name))
            root_rule.appendChild(rule)

        # delete the default rule
        root_rule.removeChildAt(0)

        # apply the renderer to the layer
        layer.setRenderer(renderer)
        layer.triggerRepaint()
```

P.S. The if statement is for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    symbol.deleteSymbolLayer(0)
    symbolLayer2 = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer()
    symbolLayer1 = QgsLinePatternFillSymbolLayer()
    [+] symbol.appendSymbolLayer(symbolLayer2)
    [+] symbol.appendSymbolLayer(symbolLayer1)
    renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)
    # get the "root" rule
    root_rule = renderer.rootRule()

    for label, expression, color_name in rules:
        # create a clone (i.e. a copy) of the default rule
        rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
        # set the label, expression and color
        rule.setLabel(label)
        rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
        if color_name == 'orange':
            [+]rule.symbol().symbolLayer(1).setColor(QColor('black'))
            [+]rule.symbol().symbolLayer(1).setDistance(3)
            rule.symbol().symbolLayer(0).setColor(QColor(color_name))

        else: rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color_name))
        root_rule.appendChild(rule)
```

I just had to use the function symbolLayer to select the right layer and then set the attributes I want. I had also to change the order I append the symbol Layers. Otherwise, the line pattern would appear under the fill layer and not above.